# Why hasn't my Nexus 6 received Android M?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, nexus-6

I've tried researching and I cannot find any explanation for this. About 2 weeks after Android 6 was released I did get a security update for lollipop but nothing since then. Everyone I know with a Nexus 5 has it, but I don't know anyone with a Nexus 6 besides myself. Why is my Nexus 6 not getting updated?

My phone is unlocked, but I do use T-Mobile.

Thanks

Comment: My Nexus 10 han't got an update either. Should we sue Google?

Comment: Google has actually released an Android Marshmallow system image for the Nexus 6. You can get it [at this page](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images). You will also find instructions on how to flash a system image on the same page. If you're not patient enough to wait for the OTA update, you can try at your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't roll out all at once, it's a staggered roll out. Relax you'll get it soon. That's how they do it. Would you complain if they pushed out the update quickly and your device bricks because of a potential problem. This is why they do small batches. Easier to replace 100 devices than replace thousends of devices.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses a staged rollout method so if a bug goes un-noticed and appears in real world use, they can stop the rollout with minimal damage. Rest assured, you will eventually receive the update. Update is rolled out in batches everyday.

http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/20/google-engineer-dan-morrill-sheds-some-light-on-the-nexus-ota-process-urges-you-to-never-clear-google-service-framework-data/

Direct link: https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1r1dz4/44_kitkat_has_started_rolling_out_on_the_n4/cdiwt6f

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in the previous answer, you can wait for the update rollout or visit [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6) and install it manually. You'd have to do a lot of reading though before you go ahead playing around with the device. But, I'm very sure it'll be fun.

All the best.!!